# SQL LAG Days since last order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, lag

Hi I am trying to create a windowed query in SQL that shows me the days since last order for each customer.

[image]

It now shows me the days in between each order.

What do I need to change in my query to have it only show the days since the last and the previous order per customer? Now it shows it for every order the customer made.

Query:

```
SELECT klantnr,besteldatum,
      DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(besteldatum) OVER(PARTITION BY klantnr ORDER BY besteldatum),besteldatum) AS DaysSinceLastOrder
FROM bestelling
GROUP BY klantnr,besteldatum;
```

Comment: Can you please paste your query here instead of a screen shot?

Comment: days since last order until *today* or some other date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to order the rows by `besteldatum` for each `klantnr`, and return the latest two using a derived table (subquery) or [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

derived table version:

```
select klantnr, besteldatum, DaysSinceLastOrder
  from (
    select klantnr, besteldatum
      , DaysSinceLastOrder = datediff(day,lag(besteldatum) over (partition by klantnr order by besteldatum),besteldatum) 
      , rn = row_number() over (partition by klantnr order by besteldatum desc)
    from bestelling
    group by klantnr, besteldatum
  ) t
where rn = 1
```

[common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) version:

```
;with cte as (
  select klantnr, besteldatum
    , DaysSinceLastOrder = datediff(day,lag(besteldatum) over (partition by klantnr order by besteldatum),besteldatum) 
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by klantnr order by besteldatum desc)
  from bestelling
  group by klantnr, besteldatum
)
select klantnr, besteldatum, DaysSinceLastOrder
from cte
where rn = 1
```

If you want one row per customer, `rn = 1` is the proper filter. If you want `n` number of latest rows, use `rn <` n+1.